# CLI vs Pure C/C++ Library for a program?

Tags: c, linux, go

**Background / Context:** I am developing a Linux NAS Server (Like FreeNAS or Rockstor) using Golang, the particular features will be a JSON-REST API so that you can interact with LVM2, shares, packages, etc.

**Question:** With respect to security, performance, and development time, what are the advantages / disadvantages / best practices of implmenting spawned processes or using a native library for certain features for a program?

**Example:** For my particular use case, the NAS management system will be using LVM2 to manage volumes. However you can use the CLI to manipulate volumes or you can attempt to use the LVM2 native C API and merge it with Golangs `cgo` package.

*EDIT: Rephrased my question / information.*

Comment: Is this the right site for that type of discussion question?

Comment: "Although you do have to run these as sudo or as root user" - did it occur to you why this is the case? Does your program that needs to run the lvm commands run as root? If not, it's not going to be able to use the library functions, presumably.

Comment: @WeatherVane Fixed. Yea, I looked at several times and I agree it is a little lengthy and not very concise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that may make using `exec` in the different variants a nogo: security and speed.

- Security: If you shell out with `system()` or friends, you must be absolutely certain that you don't include any strings in the command that may do funny stuff with your command line. It's the same basic problem as SQL code injection, just at a much lower and even more disastrous layer ([obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/), just replace "'); DROP TABLE Students;--" with valid sh code along the lines of '"; echo "pwnd', well, you get the idea).
- Speed: When you shell out to an existing program, you create a new process, and that may be the performance hit you cannot tolerate. It's perfectly ok if the task for which you shell out takes more than a few milliseconds (process creation is somewhere in the range of a millisecond on linux), but if you want more than a thousand calls per second, you definitely need to avoid this overhead.

If these two points are taken care of or proven to be non-issues, then it's perfectly ok to shell out to other processes.

Comment: Those points seem to be a non-issue, particularly my application is not a large web app so it won't be spawning 100 different processes to change volumes or share metadata. As for security, you are vulnerable to code injection if you don't check for those types of things. If you take of adding user validation and shell escaping / injection then you should be fine. I'm pretty sure you know all this but this is more for people who are looking at this question and want an aside to the comment. Thanks :)